# Java, multi-thread application,working main window when computing

Tags: java, multithreading, computation

I would like to ask for advice how to design the application. Currently, I would like to rewrite a statistical application processing large data into a multi-thread version. My primary language is C++, sorry for my slightly beginner question :-).

The existing application is based on the following model. There is a MainWindow class continuously displaying previous results involving current zoom operation (GUI). Each statistical computation is based on the own class picking up the input data, performing the computation, showing results and its visualization (based on swing).

Unfortunately, the library is not written as multi-thread. It has an undesirable consequence: while a computation is running, it is impossible to work with MainWindow (browsing all results until new are obtained); it is "frozen"...

Yesterday, I tried to propose a single conceptual update:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFame {

private void fButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
   //Get data, single thread
   Matrix A = getData();  //Input data (block matrix)
   Matrix B;              //Output data (block matrix)

   //Computation in a separate thread
   FunctionMT f = new FunctionMT (A, B);
   Thread t = new Thread(f);  
   t.start();    // Starting the thread

   //Display results in a form
   results.print(B);

   //Update graphic results
   scene.update(B);
   scene.repaint();
}
```

The sample function class FunctionMT  extends Thread library

```
public class FunctionMT extends Thread{
    private final Matrix A;
    private Matrix B;

    public FunctionMT (final Matrix A_, Matrix B_) {A = A_; B = B_;}
    public void run () { spDecomposition();}
    public void spDecomposition() { 
        for (int i = 0; i < A.size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < A.size; j++)
                B(i,j) = f(A(i,));} //Some computationally hard step
}
```

The matrix A is the input matrix, B represents the output. The computation is performed in a single thread working with FunctionMT instance...

When a computation is run in a single thread, it is possible to work with the main window. Unfortunately, results are repainted before the computation is stopped.

I tried to add a join method()

```
 ...
 Thread t = new Thread(f);  
 t.start();    // Starting the thread

 try{t.join();}  //Wait for its end
 catch(InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

 results.print(B);

 scene.update(B);
 scene.repaint();
 ...
```

which waits until the results are processed.Unfortunately, it makes the main window frozen.

How to propose a multi-thread computation to be able to work with a main window during the computation as well as the form waits until the computation is finished?

Is it possible to add some function that processs system messages into for cycle ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.size; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < A.size; j++)
          processSystemMessages();
          B(i,j) = f(A(i,));}
```

Another solution may join the computation algorithms and showing the results into the same thread, but it looks ugly :-) and breaks the design pattern.

Thank you very much for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**UPDATE**: looser coupling

```java
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private void fButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

        // ...

        FunctionMT f = new FunctionMT (A, B, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                results.print(B);
                scene.update(B);
                scene.repaint();
            }
        });
        Thread t = new Thread(f);
        t.start();

        // Wait for computation:
        // won't do it here.
        // results.print(B);
        // scene.update(B);
        // scene.repaint();
    }
}
```

```java
public class FunctionMT extends Runnable {

    // ...

    private Runnable callback;

    public FunctionMT (final Matrix A_, Matrix B_, Runnable callback) {

        // ...

        this.callback = callback;
    }

    private void spDecomposition() {

        // Do computation.

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ nandsito: Thanks for your comment. The problem is that a computation, printing results and updating the scene are joined to the same thread and method. It leads to the huge redefinition of the class FunctionMT (references to the forms, graphic objects, etc...). Unfortunately, it breaks a design pattern...

Comment: @justik your worry is legitimate. I updated my answer, please see if it fits your needs

Comment: @ nandsito: Great, it works! Thank you very much again ! Only a short comment: Instead of SwingUtilities.html.invokeLater it should be SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Comment: @justik my mistake... i miscopied the javadoc url